# vuejs-native computed style transform error

Tags: vue.js, vue-native

I have a little trouble with vuejs-native, i try to do a computed style transform, and i get this error :

```
[Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...transform.forEach...')"
```

Here is the full log :

```
[Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...transform.forEach...')"
- node_modules/vue-native-core/build.js:383:20 in warn
- node_modules/vue-native-core/build.js:466:12 in handleError
- node_modules/vue-native-core/build.js:612:22 in <unknown>
- node_modules/vue-native-core/build.js:549:6 in nextTickHandler
- node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
- node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:123:25 in <unknown>
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:152:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:200:17 in _callImmediatesPass
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:464:30 in callImmediates
* [native code]:null in callImmediates
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:320:6 in __callImmediates
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:135:6 in <unknown>
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:297:10 in __guard
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:134:17 in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```